# Outlook 2013 table border not respected

Tags: css, html-table, html-email, border-layout

In Internet Explorer we achieved the desired result:

[image]

But in Outlook 2013 the border is removed from the table or only partially shown:

[image]

We can't seem to find a way to figure out how to get the same look in Outlook as it is in Internet Explorer. One caveat is, the CSS is split in two parts, the first part cannot be altered only the second part. Because the first part is a default we use in other e-mail templates working with PowerShell.

**The code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            font-family: verdana;
            background-color: white;
        }

        p {
            font-size: 14px;
            margin-left: 10px;
        }

        table {
            font-size: 14px;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            border: 1px none;
            padding: 3px;
            text-align: left;
            padding-right: 10px;
            margin-left: 10px;
        }

        td,
        th {
            font-size: 14px;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            border: 1px none;
            padding: 3px;
            text-align: left;
            padding-right: 10px
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <p>Details per matrix file:</p>
    <style>

        #matrixTable {
            border: 1px solid Black;
            border-collapse: separate;
            border-spacing: 0px 0.6em;
            max-width: 97%;
            min-width: 600px;
            padding: 10px;
        }

        #matrixTitle {
            border: none;
            background-color: lightgrey;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 6px;
        }

        #matrixHeader {
            font-weight: normal;
            letter-spacing: 5pt;
            font-style: italic;
        }

        #matrixFileInfo {
            font-weight: normal;
            font-size: 12px;
            font-style: italic;
            text-align: center;
        }

        #LegendTable {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            border: 1px solid Black;
            table-layout: fixed;
            width: 600px;
        }

        #LegendTable td {
            text-align: center;
        }

        #probTitle {
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        #probTypeWarning {
            background-color: orange;
        }

        #probTypeError {
            background-color: red;
        }

        #probTypeInfo {
            background-color: lightgrey;
        }
    </style>
    <table id="matrixTable">
        <tr>
            <th id="matrixTitle" colspan="8"><a href="\\location\file.xlsx">BEL MTX-CEM-CBR Antoing.xlsx</a></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th id="matrixFileInfo" colspan="8">Last change: Gijbels, Brecht (Braine L’Alleud) BEL @ 12/09/2018 13:56:03</th>
        </tr>


        <th id="matrixHeader" colspan="8">Settings</th>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>ComputerName</td>
            <td>Path</td>
            <td>Action</td>
            <td>Duration</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="probTypeWarning"></td>
            <td><a href="\\somewhere\ID 1 - Settings.html">1</a></td>
            <td><a href="\\somewhere\ID 1 - Settings.html">BELSFANTO0128.GROUPHC.NET</a></td>
            <td><a href="\\somewhere\ID 1 - Settings.html">E:\DEPARTMENTS_NEW</a></td>
            <td><a href="\\somewhere\ID 1 - Settings.html">Check</a></td>
            <td><a href="\\somewhere\ID 1 - Settings.html">00:00:01</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br><br>
    <table id="LegendTable">
        <tr>
            <td id="probTypeError" style="border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid Black;width: 200px;">Error</td>
            <td id="probTypeWarning" style="border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid Black;width: 200px;">Warning</td>
            <td id="probTypeInfo" style="border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid Black;width: 200px;">Information</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: use inline styles for table borders like you did in the "LegendTable". Set the border directly via style="" or with border="1"

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, I tried `<table style="border: 1px solid Black;border-collapse: separate;border-spacing: 0px 0.6em; border:black">`

Answer (score 1):

I haven't figured out how to fix it, but I can tell you where your problem is coming from. In the first block of CSS, your table, th, and td elements have the property "border: 1px none;", which negates your border styling. Commenting out those lines allows the border to appear.

Comment: Indeed, that seems to do the trick. Now I just need to figure out how to do this without modifying the first block of CSS. Thx for pointing me to the right direction.